# publish application win forms - change Deployment Provider url

Tags: c#, publish

I created project using second project (I copied and change). And I want publish my app. In options I changed Publishing Folder Location and Installation Folder URL, but when I want install app I get error and in details Deployment Provider url is not change and it generate error.

```
SOURCES
Deployment url          : http://www.ddd.pl/instalki/JPK/sss.application
Deployment Provider url     : http://www.ddd.pl/instalki/AVA/sss.application
```

Deployment url is ok but Deployment provider url is incorrect.

When I can change it?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Not found (404) because url is incorrect

Comment: I try change wrong URL but this do not does effect in release